# How to write a Controller variable value back to the HTML page that sent the Ajax request without a page refresh?

Tags: java, ajax, spring, spring-mvc

The following JavaScript

```
new Ajax.Request('/orders/check_first_last/A15Z2W2', 
{asynchronous:true, evalScripts:true, 
parameters:{first:$('input_initial').value, 
last:$('input_final').value, 
order_quantity:$('input_quantity').value}});
```

triggers an Ajax call to the `checkFirstLast` method in the `OrderController`:

```
@Controller
@RequestMapping("/orders")
public OrderController {

   @RequestMapping("/check_first_last/{code}")
   @ResponseBody
   public String checkFirstLast(@PathVariable String code, 
        @RequestParam int first, 
        @RequestParam int last, 
        @RequestParam("order_quantity") int orderQuantity)  {
       Integer newResult = new Integer(last - first);
       return newResult.toString();
  }
}
```

If I want to write the `newResult` String from the `checkFirstLast` method into the `result_text` HTML element on the page that sends the Ajax request, replacing the value set by the `initialResult` JSTL variable:

```
<h2 id="result_text"><c:out value="${initialResult}"/></h2>
```

what change would I need to make to the controller method above (`checkFirstLast`), now that I have already included the Jackson JSON library in my project?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

the flow in ajax is:

1. send request with javascript to server
2. process request on server
3. sent response back to client
4. process response with javascript and update the page

The 4th step is missing in the code you provide.

It seems to me you are using [the prototype javascript framework](http://www.prototypejs.org/), is this correct?
If you look at [the documentation for ajax requests](http://www.prototypejs.org/api/ajax/request) and [the ajax options](http://www.prototypejs.org/api/ajax/options) you will see you can specify callback function when the requests was handled with success, or when a failure occured.

Change your javascript to:

```
new Ajax.Request(
    '/orders/check_first_last/A15Z2W2', 
    {
        asynchronous:true,
        evalScripts:true, 
        parameters:
        {
            first:$('input_initial').value, 
            last:$('input_final').value, 
            order_quantity:$('input_quantity').value
        },
        onSuccess: function(transport) 
        {
             $('result_text').update(transport.responseText);
        }
    }
);
```

and let me know what it gives.

Answer (score 1):

This is an `abstract` controller that I wrote to handle Ajax. This actually is from the `Struts` example on `DispatchAction`.

```
public ModelAndView handleRequest(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response) throws Exception {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        AjaxResponse ajaxResponse = null;
        String parameter = "command";

        try {
            String methodName = request.getParameter(parameter);
            Method method = getMethod(methodName);

            ajaxResponse = invokeMethod(request, response, method);         
        } catch (Exception e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            logger.error(e.getLocalizedMessage());
            ajaxResponse = toXmlException(e);
        }

        if (ajaxResponse != null) {
            //Finally
            response.setContentType(ajaxResponse.getContentType());
            response.setHeader("Cache-Control", "no-cache");
            OutputStream out = response.getOutputStream();
            out.write(ajaxResponse.getResponseText().getBytes());
            out.flush();
        }

        return null;
    }
```

As you can see, A javascript is sent to the server, which is then dispatched by the `DispatcherServlet` to the controller. The controller then `invokes` the correct method call and returns a response through `response.getOutputStream().write(....)`.

The controller then **must** return a `null` so that the DispatcherServlet does nothing in return.

In my case, `AjaxResponse` is an interface and the response can be either `XmlAjaxResponse` or `JsonAjaxResponse`.

The java client then handles the response returned from the server (in this case, controller).

You need to add in a response to your side. Hope this helps.